# Django views function skip urls keywords

Tags: django

```
#1. 
path('<str:lang>/request/', views.request.get_request),

#2. 
LangMiddleware

def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
    lang = view_kwargs.get('lang')
    settings.LANGUAGE_CODE = 'lang

    pass

#3. 
views.py ---> def get_request(request): <--- I don't want to put 'lang' param
```

I have a lang keyword in `urls`, this keyword only use inside of `LangMiddleware`

It don't need it inside of views, therefor I don't want to put keyword in every function.

anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Can you share your middleware?

Comment: middleware updated, I'm from Laravel, In Laravel, they use custom lang files to help translate. So I try to create my own translate class to process this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to remove `lang` from the keyword arguments by using `pop` in your middleware

```
lang = view_kwargs.pop('lang')
```